# Standard deviation (or sum of squares) of disjoint range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a range that I sum over with this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(sheet!F:F,sheet!A:A,A2,sheet!I:I,"")
```

That is, there are two conditions: on the other sheet, the value in column A has to match that of A2 here, and the value in column I has to be blank.

I want to find the standard deviation of these values instead. It is enough to find the sum of their squares and use math. I've tried to do this with `SUMPRODUCT` and array formulas but no luck so far. Any ideas?

If possible I'd like to avoid VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=STDEV(IF((Sheet1!A1:A1000 = A2)*(Sheet1!I1:I1000 = ""),Sheet1!F1:F1000))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: .          .       .   Very clever!